# Something happened and PDFs no longer open in new browser tab

Tags: jspdf-autotable

I am running pdf-autotable v2.3.2 alongside jspdf v1.3.3 in a ReactJS app. I have changed no code, but PDFs that used to show up in a new Chrome tab (and look beautiful, BTW) now no longer display.

The tab opens with the title Untitled, a URL like data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9...(thousands of characters)...Ci9CaXRzUGVyQ29tcG9uZW50IDgKL0ZpbHRlciAvRENURGVjb2RlCi9MZW5ndGggNDAyMj4+CnN0cmVhbQr/2P/hABhFeGlmAABJSSoACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/+wAEUR1Y2t5AAEABAAAADwAAP/hAzFodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD%E2%80%A6%E2%80%A6 and an empty web page.

My pdf/autotable code is:

```
  printGrid() {
    let doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
    const totalPagesExp = "{total_pages_count_string}";

    let pageContent = function (data) {

        // HEADER
        doc.setFontSize(20);
        doc.setTextColor(40);
        doc.setFontStyle('normal');
        doc.addImage(getBase64ImgGlobal(), 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 15, 10, 10);
        doc.text(fullReportName, data.settings.margin.left + 15, 22);

        // FOOTER
        var str = "Page " + data.pageCount;
        if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
            str = str + " of " + totalPagesExp;
        }
        doc.setFontSize(10);
        doc.text(str, data.settings.margin.left, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10);
    };

    let _this = this;

    doc.autoTable(this.getPdfColumns(), this.getPdfData(), {
        addPageContent: pageContent,
        margin: {top: 30},
        createdHeaderCell: function(cell, data) { _this.alignCol(cell, data) },
        createdCell: function(cell, data) { _this.alignCol(cell, data) }
    });

    if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
        doc.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);
    }

    doc.setProperties({
      title: fullReportName
    });

    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
  };
```

I then commented out all my own code and pasted in your simplest example:

```
var columns = ["ID", "Country", "Rank", "Capital"];
var data = [
    [1, "Denmark", 7.526, "Copenhagen"],
    [2, "Switzerland",  7.509, "Bern"],
    [3, "Iceland", 7.501, "Reykjavík"],
    [4, "Norway", 7.498, "Oslo"],
    [5, "Finland", 7.413, "Helsinki"]
];

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.autoTable(columns, data);
doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

And the exact same thing happened. Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `doc.save()` instead of `doc.output()`